# How to use onchange with autocomplete material ui?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hooks

With the method handleChange is handled OnChange event of the Form Input with Hooks style that set the state off the object.

The handleChange function in turn calls setLocation which updates the location state with the new value.

To make user data entry easier, I decided to change the city field to an autocomplete, but I failed to capture the value of the autocomplete.
In the documentation he tells me that I need to pass two arguments but I can't understand very well

```
function(event: object, value: any) => void
event: The event source of the callback
value: null
```

How can I access the value of the field and put it into my function to insert the data?

```
        <Autocomplete
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        value={location.City}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={list.City}
        classes={{
          option: classes.option,
        }}
        autoHighlight
        getOptionLabel={option => typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.City}
        renderOption={option => (
          <React.Fragment>

            {option.City} -{option.State}
          </React.Fragment>
        )}

         renderInput={params => (
           <TextField {...params} label="City"  value={location.City}  margin="normal" variant="outlined" style={{ width: 220 }} inputProps={{
             ...params.inputProps,
             autoComplete: 'disabled', // disable autocomplete and autofill
           }}/>
         )}
       />
```

Comment: Well I have good and bad news for you,
Good news is I faced the same problem and undesrtand what's going on,
bad news is I didn't fixed it either.

if you have the same problem as me: your autocomplete messes with axios/async.
If it's same as my problem you have to somehow clear axios everytime you hit a key

sorry that I can't give proper answer but maybe it will help !

I'll check you back tomorrow here maybe someone helps you and help me fixe my problem too  ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the value of the input as the user types, you need to use `onInputChange`. The `onChange` handler runs when the user selects an option from the drop down.

```
export default function ComboBox() {
  function handleInputChange(event, value) {
    console.log(value);
  }

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option: FilmOptionType) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4ogyp)

Answer (score 2):

the react SyntheticEvent set null target in an Asynchronous requests, try to use

> event.persist()

on the event

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

```
 const handleOnChangeText=(event)=> {     
    event.persist();
    console.log(event)    
    let active = true;
    setOpen(true);
    if (!loading) {
      return undefined;
    }
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://country.register.gov.uk/records.json?page-size=5000');
      await sleep(1e3); // For demo purposes.
      const countries = await response.json();
      if (active) {
        setOptions(Object.keys(countries).map(key => countries[key].item[0]) as CountryType[]);
      }
      active = false;
    })();   
}



<Autocomplete
      id="comboboxAsync"
      disableOpenOnFocus
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      open={open}
      onInputChange={handleOnChangeText}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is getting retrieved under this pattern: id-option-numberOfOption, that's why I had to split the retrieved value in order to update the state

```
const handleAutoCompleteChange = (event, value) => {
          this.setState({ ...this.state, [event.target.id.split("-")[0]]: value });
          console.log([event.target.id.split("-")[0]],value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use mui-autocomplete npm its easy and less coding  with more options(Like avatar view asynchronus calls).You should try it out. Here is the example for more info visit here. 
[http://mui-autocomplete.com/home]

```
`import React from 'react';
 import MuiAutocomplete from 'mui-autocomplete';
 const cities = [
 {
   id: 1,
   name: "Alabama",
   code: "AL"
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: "Alaska",
   code: "AK"
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   name: "American Samoa",
   code: "AS"
 }];
 function Home () {
   return (
     <div>
      <MuiAutocomplete
       placeholder="Countries"
       name="countries"
       setvalue={1}
       setdata={cities}
       variant="outlined"
       template={{
        title: 'name'
       }}
      />
    </div>
    );
 }`
```