# ReactJs Search inside a list of items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using the  React material-ui search bar to search for items in a list. I have created the search bar component that takes the array of items from the list component as a property.

problem:  I want when searching for an item to show only the item in the parent list. I have followed the below tutorials but none works for me.

[Simple search form in REACT using hooks](https://dev.to/asimdahall/simple-search-form-in-react-using-hooks-42pg)

[Create a Simple Search Component in React.js using React Hooks](https://medium.com/shashank-singh/create-a-simple-search-component-in-react-js-using-react-hooks-f8909166d1bd)

[How to use onchange with autocomplete material ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59258148/how-to-use-onchange-with-autocomplete-material-ui)

Below is the code of the components:

List component:

```
<List
  component="nav"
  aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
  subheader={
    <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
      <SearchBar items={items} /> //Calling SeacrhBar Component
    </ListSubheader>
  }
>
  {items.map((item, index, list) => (
    <Fragment key={item.id}>
      <ListItem
        button
        key={item.id}
        onClick={() => changeSubList(0)}
        onDoubleClick={() =>
            changeSubList(item)
        }
      >
        <ListItemText primary={item.name}/>
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={openItemID === item.id} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
          </ListItem>
          <item itemId={item.id}/>
        </List>
      </Collapse>
    {index < list.length - 1 ? <Divider/> : null}
  </Fragment>
  ))}
</List>
```

Searchbar component:

```
      const SearchBar = ({items}) => {
        const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
        const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
         const handleChange = event => {
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
        };
        useEffect(() => {
            const results = items.filter(deivce =>
                deivce.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
            );
            setSearchResults(results);
        }, [searchTerm]);
    
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    value={searchTerm}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <ul>
                    {searchResults.map(item => (
                        <li key={item.id}>{items}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
export default SearchBar;
```

the items are array of item as follows:

```
"items ": Array(3)
 0: {id: 1, attributes: {…}, groupId: 1, name: "1", uniqueId: "1236547"}
 1: {id: 2, attributes: {…}, groupId: 1, name: "2", uniqueId: "98766541"}
 2: {id: 7, attributes: {…}, groupId: 3, name: "2", uniqueId: "98745698"}
    
 {
   "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "Course ": "English",
            "Workhours": 80
        },
        "groupId": 1,
        "name": "1",
        "uniqueId": "1236547",
        "status": "still working"
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the data structure of `items`

Comment: @Alloylo, Where is the hook? Where did you define the hook and how does it look like?

Comment: Sorry @hotcakedev for the distraction. I am new to react and do not know where to use the hook in the search bar component or in the List component.

Comment: @Alloylo, You have to pass the event handler which use `useState` to set keyword into `searchBar` component.

Comment: @Alloylo, Can you make the CodePen?

Comment: I update my search component can you please check it

Comment: does the search itself work though?

Comment: No, when trying to write one letter in the search bar a new blank page open and the error is as follows : Objects are not valid as a React child. The  error occurred in the <li> component

Comment: the problem has been solved thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all,  I have solved the problem. After the last update of the code just add the searchcomponent in the list component as the following code.

```
    return (
    <List component="nav"
          aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
          subheader={
              <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
              </ListSubheader>
          }>
        <SearchBar items={items}/>
    </List>
);
```